# Python urllib2 and php port conflict

Tags: php, python, php-fpm, port, socket

I have python script that is called by PHP via exec. It uses urllib2 and beautifulsoup.

The php-fpm runs on port 8000, i have different ports for different pool and I assume they are ok when php-fpm start as everything works smoothly.

Here's a problem. Sometimes PHP-FPM will crash but restarting complains that port is in us. I also notice that the python scripts are running. They are probably on a long time out.

What I cannot figure out is why a python script will interfere with PHP-FPM as it must be on its own  process. Why does it take the entire php-fpm and all pools with it. W

Is it conflicting with ports? I have tried changing fpm to use different port but that is not helping.

this occurs randomly, butonce the conditions are met, the FPM servers are gone.

any clues or direction to figure this out will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is on Linux. It is likely that the port is still assigned to the old process (it might even still be a zombie).

If this happens you can take a look at the status of the ports, e.g. by running 'netstat -nltp ' to see what's up with the port.